# Multiple-Value Ranking in C++

Tags: c++, boost, ranking

I have a vector which is such that;

`vector<pair<Point, vector<double> > >`

[Point(x,y)] , [ double value1 | double value2 | ... | double valueN ]

What I want to do is ranking this vector according to the each value and then calculate the average rank for each element of the vector. The element with the highest average will be the winner.

With a straightforward approach, I think I can create vector of pairs  such that;

```
vector<pair<Point(x,y), double value1> >

vector<pair<Point(x,y), double value2> >

...

vector<pair<Point(x,y), double valueN> >
```

Then sort each vector, store the ranks etc. while keeping a unique ID based on the Point(x,y). However, what I wonder is whether there is a more elegant way to do it using C++ with Boost ?

Comment: Is the size of the interior `std::vector<double>` the same always?  Is it a compile-time constant?  What if the interior `std::vector<double>` differs in size between one element and another?  Why are you using `pair` and not, say, a named structure containing a point and a vector?  Do you only need the "best" element?  Are the `Point`s unique, guaranteed?  About how big is `N`?  How big is the outer vector -- 10s?  1000s?  1000000s?

Comment: Size of std::vector<double> is constant and a small number such as 2-3. Additionally, the size of this vector is the same for each element. Using a named structure is also a nice idea, my C++ is a bit rusty so I used the first thing comes to my mind to be honest. For the moment, I need the best but this will change. Therefore, let's say first K elements after sorting. Yes, Points are unique indeed and the outer vector is quite small too around 20 depending on the parameters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest a custom struct:

```
struct Point { int x, y; };

template <size_t N = 3>
struct Entry {
    Point at;
    std::array<double, N> data;

    double rank() const {
        return algo::average(data.begin(), data.end()); 
    }
};
```

And use it like, e.g. with [`nth_element`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/nth_element):

```
#include <numeric>
#include <iterator>

namespace algo {
    template <typename R = double, typename It>
        R average(It b, It e) {
            return std::accumulate(b, e, R{}) / std::distance(b,e);
        }
}

// ...

struct ByRankDescending {
    template<typename Entry>
    double operator()(Entry const& a, Entry const& b) const {
        return a.rank() > b.rank();
    }
};

#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

int main() {
    std::vector<Entry<3>> entries {
        { Point{1,2}, {3,4,5} },
        { Point{3,4}, {5,6,7} },
        { Point{5,6}, {7,8,9} },
    };

    if (!entries.empty()) {
        std::nth_element(entries.begin(), entries.begin()+1, entries.end(), ByRankDescending{});

        std::cout << "Max. rank at " << entries.front().at.x << ", " << entries.front().at.y << "\n";
    }
}
```

Which prints:

```
Max. rank at 5, 6
```